# AngularJS : Undefined value returned in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-factory

I am using angularJS to build a factory that accesses a http resource. I can see the data being returned locally near the request but the data is not returned in the controller. Here is my factory:

```
myNameSpace.factory('simpleFactory', function ($http) {
var factory = {};
var customers = [];
factory.getCustomers = function () {
    $http.jsonp('http://URL&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function (data) {
        customers = data;
        return customers;
    })
}

return factory;
```

});

My controller is:

```
myNameSpace.controller('DetailsController', function ($scope, $http, simpleFactory) {
var cust = simpleFactory.getCustomers();
$scope.CustomerData = simpleFactory.getCustomers();
console.log(cust); //The value that is display here is undefined
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: That call needs time to come back - so you're `console` statement fires while that call is still in progress - search on returning from an async call in an Angular factory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $http call is an ajax asynchronous call which means you'll need to send the result through a callback.  This may help:

Here's the factory:

```
myNameSpace.factory('simpleFactory', function ($http) {
var factory = {};
factory.getCustomers = function (callback) {
    $http.jsonp('http://URL&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(callback);
}

return factory;

});
```

Here's how to use it:

```
myNameSpace.controller('DetailsController', function ($scope, $http, simpleFactory) {
    simpleFactory.getTopOffenders(function(offenders) {
        $scope.topoffendersData = offenders;
    });
});
```